# Is it possible to record audio coming through headphones connected to an iPhone?

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avaudiosession

I have my headphones plugged into my iPhone. Is there any way to record the audio that is coming through my headphones and have it become a part of the final audio file? I have tried setting different options on the AVAudioSession object but the output results in the audio from the microphone being recorded and ignores whatever music/audio was playing through my headphones.

Is this even possible? If so, how would one go about implementing this?